# Determining Bounding Points of UAV Images

Tags: python, gps, imagery, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, exif

I know the EXIF data from drones contains the GPS point central to the photo to provide photo location. What I'd like is to determine the lat/lon of the four corners of the image. I've done a pretty focused Google search and also checked this site to no avail.

Does anyone have insight into how this might be done? My initial thoughts are it would somehow have to incorporate the height AGL of the drone when the image is taken, the image size in pixels, and possibly some of the camera info (focal length or such).

What I'm trying to do is set the bounding coordinates for the photo and then determine if there is a GIS asset in the image area. The photo could then be linked to the asset in the attribute table and brought up via a hotlink.

How can I find the coordinates of the photo corners?

Comment: You need some additional information in addition to AGL, image size & lens/sensor data - UAV course (or orientation of the image) and angle (if not a perfect vertical). Do you have those?

Comment: Course can actually be built from the GPS points if needed. Angle is set in the UAV before image collection (90° down if nadir, and usually 45° if flying obliques).

Comment: QGIS Full Motion Video plugin does something quite like what you're looking for, in the code you may find the equations

Comment: see also https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/56596/how-do-i-calculate-the-ground-footprint-of-an-aerial-camera

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38099915/calculating-coordinates-of-an-oblique-aerial-image

Milan Zelenka's Java code for these calculations can be found at https://github.com/zelenmi6/thesis