# Get coordinates from EXIF

Tags: coordinates, latitude-longitude, exif

I wonder if it is possible to know if with the EXIF ​​data of a photo you can get the angle with respect to x or y (latitude or longitude) to position it on a map. Or given the EXIF ​​data to calculate the coordinates of the four corners of the image.
I have been looking for this information for days and I have not been able to find it.

Kind regards.

So far, these are the data that I could collect.

Using EXIF tool

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 11.60
File Name                       : test.jpg
Directory                       : C:/Users/MyMachine/Desktop
File Size                       : 5.3 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2019:07:19 08:55:14-03:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2019:08:06 15:50:43-03:00
File Creation Date/Time         : 2019:08:06 15:50:43-03:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-rw-
File Type                       : JPEG
File Type Extension             : jpg
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
Exif Byte Order                 : Little-endian (Intel, II)
Image Description               : DCIM\100MEDIA\DJI_0022.JPG
Camera Model Name               : FC330
Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Software                        : v01.19.5266
Modify Date                     : 2018:01:05 09:40:18
Y Cb Cr Positioning             : Centered
Exposure Time                   : 1/1245
F Number                        : 2.8
Exposure Program                : Program AE
ISO                             : 100
Exif Version                    : 0230
Date/Time Original              : 2018:01:05 09:40:18
Create Date                     : 2018:01:05 09:40:18
Components Configuration        : -, Cr, Cb, Y
Compressed Bits Per Pixel       : 3.498599333
Shutter Speed Value             : 1/1244
Aperture Value                  : 2.8
Exposure Compensation           : -0.344
Max Aperture Value              : 2.8
Subject Distance                : 0 m
Metering Mode                   : Center-weighted average
Light Source                    : Unknown
Flash                           : No flash function
Focal Length                    : 3.6 mm
Make                            : DJI
Speed X                         : +0.00
Speed Y                         : +0.00
Speed Z                         : +0.00
Pitch                           : -6.20
Yaw                             : +15.30
Roll                            : -8.70
Camera Pitch                    : -90.00
Camera Yaw                      : +15.90
Camera Roll                     : +0.00
Flashpix Version                : 0010
Color Space                     : sRGB
Exif Image Width                : 4000
Exif Image Height               : 3000
Interoperability Index          : R98 - DCF basic file (sRGB)
Interoperability Version        : 0100
Exposure Index                  : undef
File Source                     : Digital Camera
Scene Type                      : Unknown (0)
Custom Rendered                 : Normal
Exposure Mode                   : Auto
White Balance                   : Manual
Digital Zoom Ratio              : undef
Focal Length In 35mm Format     : 20 mm
Scene Capture Type              : Standard
Gain Control                    : None
Contrast                        : Normal
Saturation                      : Normal
Sharpness                       : Hard
Device Setting Description      : (Binary data 4 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Subject Distance Range          : Unknown
GPS Version ID                  : 0.0.0.0
GPS Latitude Ref                : South
GPS Longitude Ref               : West
GPS Altitude Ref                : Above Sea Level
XP Comment                      : 0.90.142
XP Keywords                     : N
Serial Number                   : 15711eff16ff706a39ff24ff5f5bff78
Compression                     : JPEG (old-style)
Thumbnail Offset                : 41984
Thumbnail Length                : 7984
About                           : DJI Meta Data
Format                          : image/jpeg
Absolute Altitude               : +212.63
Relative Altitude               : +63.50
Gimbal Roll Degree              : +0.00
Gimbal Yaw Degree               : +15.90
Gimbal Pitch Degree             : -90.00
Flight Roll Degree              : -8.70
Flight Yaw Degree               : +15.30
Flight Pitch Degree             : -6.20
Flight X Speed                  : +0.00
Flight Y Speed                  : +0.00
Flight Z Speed                  : +0.00
Cam Reverse                     : 0
Gimbal Reverse                  : 0
Version                         : 7.0
Has Settings                    : False
Has Crop                        : False
Already Applied                 : False
MPF Version                     : 0010
Number Of Images                : 2
MP Image Flags                  : Dependent child image
MP Image Format                 : JPEG
MP Image Type                   : Large Thumbnail (VGA equivalent)
MP Image Length                 : 291239
MP Image Start                  : 5306203
Dependent Image 1 Entry Number  : 0
Dependent Image 2 Entry Number  : 0
Image UID List                  : (Binary data 66 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Total Frames                    : 1
Image Width                     : 4000
Image Height                    : 3000
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:2 (2 1)
Aperture                        : 2.8
Image Size                      : 4000x3000
Megapixels                      : 12.0
Scale Factor To 35 mm Equivalent: 5.5
Shutter Speed                   : 1/1245
Thumbnail Image                 : (Binary data 7984 bytes, use -b option to extract)
GPS Altitude                    : 212.6 m Above Sea Level
GPS Latitude                    : 32 deg 24' 1.46" S
GPS Longitude                   : 57 deg 25' 32.13" W
Preview Image                   : (Binary data 291239 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Circle Of Confusion             : 0.005 mm
Field Of View                   : 84.0 deg
Focal Length                    : 3.6 mm (35 mm equivalent: 20.0 mm)
GPS Position                    : 32 deg 24' 1.46" S, 57 deg 25' 32.13" W
Hyperfocal Distance             : 0.86 m
Light Value                     : 13.3
-- press RETURN --
```

Comment: The camera would need either 2 GPS readings or an electronic compass to get the angle

Comment: Your DJI drone has a built in magnetometer so you can use the yaw values to get the angle of the camera at the time of capture.  For corners of the image?  See this link https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330595/getting-coordinates-of-pixel-from-georeferenced-drone-photo   this link    https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258190/determining-bounding-points-of-uav-images

Comment: The only thing is how are you going to get the  coordinates and what software are you going to use it ?

Comment: PROBERT I have the center coordinates and the extent on the image to place over a map layer. Given the suggestion of Drew Noakes you have several ways to calculate this. One if with the center lonlat of the pic and another point into the image. I haven't the second point. Other if with the lonlat of the center and the angle, as @Drew Noakes suggests. I trying using this information so if it can place the image with the right orientation over the map layer, before using ortophotos data. BTW this is for a website which I am building. There are several EXIF js library where u can find this data

Comment: is this a vertical image? and if so is this an orthorectified image?  without orthorectification, any direct calculation of the image corners using angles and distance (altitude and horizontal pixel count?) from nadir (your lat/long) will be flawed due to the fact that the ground sample distance of each pixel on uneven terrain is not uniform and therefore you cannot assume that each pixel accounts for x feet horizontally in your calulations.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the information you want is available via these tags:

```
Gimbal Roll Degree              : +0.00
Gimbal Yaw Degree               : +15.90
Gimbal Pitch Degree             : -90.00
Flight Roll Degree              : -8.70
Flight Yaw Degree               : +15.30
Flight Pitch Degree             : -6.20
Flight X Speed                  : +0.00
Flight Y Speed                  : +0.00
Flight Z Speed                  : +0.00
```

Note that these are angles in three dimensions. If you just want to know angle relative to latitude and longitude, use the *yaw* value as per:

[image]

I'm not completely certain, but I expect that the flight angle gives the yaw of the drone relative to the ground lat/lng axes, and the gimbal yaw gives the angle of the camera relative to the drone. You'll need to sum these together.

Comment: Wow, thanks, man. I will dig into it and I let you know. but I think this approach is the right one.